# meter un echo de php en un archivo de javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy implementando en un web que hice hace tiempo un sistema multilenguaje con php, html y un archivo de javascript.

Un archivo de idioma en PHP.

```
<?php
#Jscript.js
define("TRAD_JsDescription","Faltan menos de ");
define("TRAD_JsDescription2","Faltan ");
define("TRAD_JsDescription3"," caractéres");
?>
```

El codigo de html que llama a javascript es através de un formulario en un evento onkeyup

```
<textarea name="descripcion" placeholder="descripcion" onkeyup="countChars(this);" maxlength="255"></textarea>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return guardar()" value="Guardar" />
```

Y en javascript tengo varias funciones.

```
//Conteo de caractéres para input descripción
function countChars(obj) {
    var maxLength = 255;
    var strLength = obj.value.length;
    var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);

    if (charRemain <= 5) {
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = '<?php include "../../php/phpScript.php"; ?><span style="color: red;"><?php echo TRAD_JsDescription; ?> ' + charRemain + ' <?php echo TRAD_JsDescription3; ?></span>';
        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = '<?php include "../../php/phpScript.php"; ?><span style="color: green;"><?php echo TRAD_JsDescription2; ?> ' + charRemain + ' <?php echo TRAD_JsDescription3; ?></span>';
    }
}

function guardar() {
    if (confirm('Va ha crear un registro. ¿Está seguro?')) {
        alert('El registro fue creado con exito');
        return true;

    }
    alert('El registro no fue creado');
    return false;
}
```

Necesito saber como hacer que me imprima el valor del texto en el idioma de la sesión.

He hecho muchos intentos, visto varias páginas y el chatgpt tampoco acierta.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: hola, tu entiendes que javascript se ejecuta de lado del cliente y php del lado del navegador? me dices si no para explicarte...

Comment: Lo que @ArcanisGK507 trata de decir es que Javascript se ejecuta en el cliente y PHP en el Servidor

Answer (score 2):

Yo haría algo así:

Digamos que tu archivo de constantes se llama `idioma.es.php`, el cual tiene

```
<?php
#Jscript.js
define("TRAD_JsDescription","Faltan menos de ");
define("TRAD_JsDescription2","Faltan ");
define("TRAD_JsDescription3"," caractéres");
?>
```

Debes crear un archivo adicional, que le llamaremos `idioma.js.php`, este archivo creará un script JS automáticamente en base a los datos de las constantes del otro archivo

```
<?php
include "idioma.es.php";
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
$all_constants = get_defined_constants(true);
echo "const constantes = ".json_encode($all_constants['user']).";";
?>
```

Luego en el HTML lo ingreso como script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="idioma.js.php"></script>
```

Y con esto tengo las constantes del idioma y las puedo aplicar donde quiera

```
//Esto imprimirá en la consola del navegador
console.log(constantes.TRAD_JsDescription); // Faltan menos de 

//esto lanzará una alerta
alert(constantes.TRAD_JsDescription);
```

Comment: vas por buen camino XD

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias, he editado la respuesta intentando clarificar lo que me has señalado.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que he hecho no me ha funcionado.

En la página que contiene el botón llama a la función de javascript a través del evento onclick="return eliminar()"

```
<td><a href="del_register.php?Del=<?php echo $row['id_mov']; ?>" onclick="return eliminar()"><img src="../../../images/delete.png" alt="<?php echo TRAD_btDel_Register; ?>" title="<?php echo TRAD_btDel_Register; ?>"></td>
```

La función la tengo en el archivo jscript.js

```
function eliminar() {
    if (confirm(console.log(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction))) {
        alert(console.log(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction2));
        return true;

    }
    alert(console.log(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction3));
    return false;
}
```

He creado un archivo, lang.js.inc.php,  con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
require('../session/cookie.php');
ob_start();
session_start();
include '../php/phpScript.php';

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
$all_constants = get_defined_constants(true);
echo "const constantes = ".json_encode($all_constants['user']).";";
?>
```

En phpScript.php tengo la clase que llama a los archivos de lenguaje según la sesión del usuario

```
class mylanguage {
    
    function get_language() {
        return $this->language;
    }
    // load language setting 
    function load_language($lang) {
        $default_language="es";
        $this->language=$lang;
        switch ($this->get_language()) {
         case "es":
             require_once '/volume1/web/comunidad_mtl_test/locales/lang-'.$this->get_language().'.inc.php';
        break;
         case "en":
             require_once '/volume1/web/comunidad_mtl_test/locales/lang-'.$this->get_language().'.inc.php';
        break;
         case "ca":
             require_once '/volume1/web/comunidad_mtl_test/locales/lang-'.$this->get_language().'.inc.php';
       break;
         default:
         // default language is 
             require_once '/volume1/web/comunidad_mtl_test/locales/lang-'.$default_language.'.inc.php';
        break;
        }

    }
        
}

// register session to change language

if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $_SESSION['language']="es";
}

$mylang=new mylanguage();
$mylang->load_language($_SESSION['language']);

if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    switch($_GET['lang']) {
        case "es":
        $_SESSION['language']="es";
        break;
        case "en":
        $_SESSION['language']="en";
        break;
        case "ca":
        $_SESSION['language']="ca";
        break;
    }
}
```

Con todo esto, no aparece ningún alert.

Comment: alert(console.log())?????! alert -> Muestra una cajita de mensaje, console.log -> escribe algo en la consola. Esto no es pokemon, no puedes hacerte con todos a la vez. Console.log **NO SIRVE PARA IMPRIMIR TEXTO**. JS se ejecuta en el contexto de la web, para imprimir cosas se usa... bueno... HTML!! Te recomiendo aprender lo básico de JS primero, veo muchísimos errores que no tienen sentido alguno. Si no escribes JS válido, es difícil juzgar dónde está el error, pues todo el código es un error enorme que acaba liándose. Además, esto no es una respuesta! Usa el enlace editar de tu pregunta anda.

Comment: Estimado el texto lo rescatas con `constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction`, puedes mostrar ese texto en la consola con `console.log(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction)`, en una alert con `alert(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction)`  en un confirm `confirm(constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction)`, dentro de un div `IDdeUnDiv.innertText=constantes.TRAD_JsDeleteFunction` y así..